# read(2) returns bigger integer than given buffer length

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I use below linux read() functions below in my code

> https://linux.die.net/man/2/read

```
 char buffer[1024];
 size_t size = read( m_fd , buffer, 1024);
```

socket descriptor "m_fd" is set as non-blocking as below;

```
 int flags = fcntl(m_fd, F_GETFL, 0);
 fcntl(m_fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

"m_fd" is a socket descriptor which is set as "non-blocking" in my case and I expect "size" return variable has value to be 0,-1 or the number of chars read(at most buffersize 1024 in my case) as described below;

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end
>   of file), and the file position is advanced by this number. It is not
>   an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested;
>   this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available
>   right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we
>   are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or because read() was
>   interrupted by a signal. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set
>   appropriately. In this case it is left unspecified whether the file
>   position (if any) changes.

But in case socket descriptor "m_fd" is newly created and nothing is written to it yet, read() function returns very big value like "18446744073709551615" and sets errno to EAGAIN.
I expect it to return "-1" like in other AGAIN cases.

Anybody know why read behaves this way?

Comment: Hint: `read()` returns `-1` on failure. `size_t` is `unsigned`.

Comment: Hint #2: what is `18446744073709551615` as a *signed* value?

Comment: `read()` returns an `ssize_t` (i.e.: signed), not a `size_t` (unsigned).

Comment: The read returns ssize_t (its a signed type) and not size_t as you described. What happens is that you are converting a negative return value (-1) to a size_t (which us unsigned) and that's why you are getting the 'trash' value.

Comment: ok got it. thx for the hint

Comment: Verbatim form your link: "*`ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);`*" The double-s is **not** a typo.